# Work With checked listBox

Tags: delphi

hello
 i want implement a algorithm that uses checked listbox
what i need is uses checked items data and index  from begin
how can I do it?

Answer (score 10):

I am not sure whether you want this or not.

You must use `CheckListBox1.Checked[i]` function

This code will return the checked items in the TCheckListBox along with its index.

```
for I := 0 to CheckListBox1.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if CheckListBox1.Checked[i] then
    begin
      ShowMessage('Item at index ' + IntToStr(i) + ' is selected.' + 
                  'Its value is '+ CheckListBox1.Items.Strings[i]);
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: @micheal. If that was the correct answer for you, please accept it.